# How to invoke variadic template version of ctor of boost::thread?

Tags: c++, boost

Below is my codes that failed to pass compilation of the command `g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp -Wall -lboost_thread -lboost_system`, if the amount of the arguments of the callback exceeds 9, in this example, it is when `TRY_VARIADIC` is defined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void foo(void) {}

template <typename T, typename... argTs>
void foo(T a0, argTs ...args)
{
    std::cout << a0 << std::endl;
    foo(args...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if TRY_VARIADIC
    boost::thread t(foo<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int>, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
#else
    boost::thread t(foo<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int>, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
#endif
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

The variadic version of ctor of `boost::thread` allows more than 9 arguments, but I don't know how to make the compiler choose it. Any suggestions, hints, examples are highly appreciated. Thanks. :-)

Comment: "If you need more than 9 arguments, you probably missed a few" - Source Unknown

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. According to the thread [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor):

> **Thread Constructor with arguments**
>
> ```
>  template <class F,class A1,class A2,...>
>  thread(F f,A1 a1,A2 a2,...);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Note**:
>
> Currently up to nine additional arguments `a1` to `a9` can be specified in addition to the function `f`.

You could just wrap 'em all in a `std::tuple`. Or, since you're on a compiler that supports variadic templates, you could just use `std::thread`.

Comment: If boost 1.58.0 is in concerned, in boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp, there are two undocumented variadic ctor templates. One of them has thread attributes as its first parameter. So it's possible to `thread t(attr, callback, arg0, arg1)`. That variadic ctor template is actually what I wanted to use, and it has the same constant macro as the ctor mentioned in the above example to enable/disable their availability.

Comment: @Cody It doesn't look to me as if that feature is finished (the heap_new template is still limited)

Comment: @Cody Why do you want to use it? The fact that it's hidden and undocumented suggests that this may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
boost::thread( [=]{ f(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); } );
```

the ability for `boost::thread` and `std::thread` to invoke with arguments is cute, but lambdas mostly make it obsolete.  If you have move-only data, you do need C++14, or to pass it explicitly, but that is a corner case.

Comment: Thanks, but I still want to know how to use the variadic ctor template provided by boost, of which the definition is in boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp(377). By the way, funtor can also be used in this scenario to pass variables as the arguments of the ctor of the functor.